# onclick calling two functions simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I googled this question and found lots of answers but not suited to my problem.

I am trying to make a button call multiple functions (2 to be exact) at the same time:

**JS**

```
     $(window).load(function(){
   $(function() { 
     $('.btnSave2').on('click', function(){ 
        // first function code
        html2canvas($(this).next(), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
              saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
        });
        }
      });

     // second function code
     $('canvas').appendTo('#here');  // appendTo -> selector


    });
  }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
```

I've tried everything, I'm not a web developer, I'm just trying to build a prototype of my product out of necessity for the kids in my school (I'm 14 so can't hire anyone).

Does anyone have any solution that actually works?

Comment: Why not just make an intermediary function that calls both of them and bind that to the button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Steve try this code I hope this solve your problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  // PLEASE ADD HERE JQUERY FILE
</head>
<body>
<div id="clk"> Click Here</div>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#clk').click( function(){
        morning();
        about();
        message();
    });
    function morning(){
        alert("Good Morning");   
    }

    function about(){
        alert("Hi my name is Sunny");
    }

    function message(){
        alert("I hope you are doing well...");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

To see working code [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/jszw46sL/1/)

Comment: At least now I know the problem is within this function: http://i.imgur.com/NhLBleL.png maybe there are just some codes that you can't use  for what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Give me time steve I try to fix your problem.

Comment: No problem, tell me if you need anything

Answer (score 1):

You can call include first function in second itself. like below -

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){ 
     $('.btn').on('click', function(){ 
        // first function code
        html2canvas($(this).next(), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
              saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
        });
        }
      });

     // second function code
     $('canvas').appendTo('#here');  // appendTo -> selector

    });
});
```

Comment: Your code works but I have to press the button twice

Comment: I'll come back and edit question and answer once I've found an answer. Thank you.